# Duplicate a row based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have some data as follows

| Call | Column B | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | '' |
| Test 2 | 2023-07-01 | '' |
| Test 2 | 2023-06-01 | '' |

I want to duplicate these entries based on the date.

The result would be something like

| Call | Column B | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | DTD |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | WTD |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | MTD |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | YTD |
| Test 2 | 2023-07-01 | MTD |
| Test 2 | 2023-07-01 | YTD |
| Test 3 | 2023-06-01 | YTD |

Could someone please guide me on how to duplicate based on a condition?

Some more examples:

Call on 7-18-2023. This would have a duplicate row for WTD,MTD , YTD (its in the 7-17 to 7/23 week, in the month of July, in the year of 2023).. 7-05-2023 would be MTD, and YTD ( in the month of july, in the year 2023)

I tried making a union based on different criteria for example when call date = getdate(), etc...

Comment: _"how to duplicate?"_ - 
Generally this done using either `UNION` - or `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: _"Could someone please guide me on how to duplicate based on a condition?"_ - in SQL (and in Relational Algebra, from which SQL is derived), this is done by generating a cartesian product _first_, then eliminating rows that don't meet the condition (instead of only performing the row-product if the condition is first met).

Comment: *"I want to duplicate this row Four times for day to date, week to date, month to date."* So what's the 4th duplicate! That's only 3. *"If there was a call on 7/17, it would only duplicate as a row on WTD"*  so why is 7/19? Neither are in the last week of the month.

Comment: Also what defines a week? Your dates are incomplete. Is 7/17 the 7th month of the 17th year? The 7th day of the 17th month? Something else?

Comment: What should happen with a row reporting for example 2023-06-01. This is none of DTD, WTD or MTD? Should it be selected with an empty frequency or should it not be selected at all?

Comment: @Robert A week would be if the call is within 7-17 to 7-23 say. Month would be 7-1 to the end of this month. 2023-06-01 would I guess be YTD. sorry I didnt give that info. I guess once the DTD, WTD, MTD work I could get further ranges to work. In essence 2023-06-01 would have only one row for YTD.

Comment: @ThomA. A call in 7-19 would be DTD, WTD, MTD , YTD since today is 7-19, 7-19 is in the week 7/17-7/23. Within the Month 7/1 to 7/31. And within the Year 2023 Jan 1- 2023 Dec 31. Hope that makes sense. 7-05-23 would be MTD ( in the month of july) , YTD since its in 2023.

Comment: So why is there no YTD row in your expected results? What defines when a week starts?

Comment: @ThomA. Mistake on my part I just edited it. A week would be any monday to sunday based on getdate.

Comment: But 7/19 isn't a date; how do you know what weekday it is? Dates arent the same weekday every year. We still don't know what 7/19 represents. I'd read that as the 7th month of the 19th year, so perhaps July 2019? What week is the whole of July in?

Comment: @ThomA to check if they are within the same week you could do something like datediff(ww,start_date,end_date) < 1. 07/19 means July 19th. I didnt include the year there.

Comment: @ThomA. Mistake on my behalf.. luckily for me my dataset is all 2023. Basically all of my calls outside of July will have only a duplicated YTD row. So 2023-06-01 call would have only one row for YTD. Hopefully that helps you understand my question.

Comment: As posted this is just too confusing. You have data in the output that is not in the sample data. And the output seems to be following some sort of rule about when to include MTD, YTD, etc but no idea what that rule is.

Comment: What isnt in the sample data? @SeanLange. If its today, you make a row for DTD, WTD, MTD, YTD. If its in this week but the call is not today (7/19/2023) (7/17/2023 - 7/23/2023 but not the 19th) its in  WTD,MTD, YTD. If the call is July 1st 2023, its in MTD, YTD. If the call was May 1st, Feb 1st, March1st for example its YTD.

Comment: Test 3 is in the output but not in the sample data. The other rules were not at all clear from the post. But you clarified that in the last comment. You should move that part to the question so it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of this is likely going to be problematic because I don't know how you can do this and keep it SARGable because you have to calculate date ranges on every row. But this will produce the output that you stated you want from the sample data provided. There may be some other ways to tackle this that would be more performant but nothing is coming to mind right now.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Call varchar(10)
    , ColumnB date
    , Frequency varchar(10)
)

insert @Something values
('Test 1', '2023-07-19', '')
, ('Test 2', '2023-07-01', '')
, ('Test 3', '2023-06-01', null)

select *
    
from @Something s
join 
(
    values('DTD'), ('WTD'), ('MTD'), ('YTD')
) x(Frequency) on case when convert(date, getdate()) = s.ColumnB and x.Frequency = 'DTD' then 1 
        when datepart(week, convert(date, getdate())) = datepart(week, s.ColumnB) and x.Frequency = 'WTD' then 1
        when datepart(month, convert(date, getdate())) = datepart(month, s.ColumnB) and x.Frequency = 'MTD' then 1
        when datepart(year, convert(date, getdate())) = datepart(year, s.ColumnB) and x.Frequency = 'YTD' then 1
        end = 1
order by s.Call
    , case x.Frequency 
        when 'DTD' then 1 
        when 'WTD' then 2 
        when 'MTD' then 3 
        when 'YTD' then 4 
        end --this will order correctly on the small sample but in a large result set you would want to control the order.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this with a view. I would do a join with the original table and a table with the frequency values you specified. On that join, I would have a condition that would always return true.

For example:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT 
    'Test1' AS [Call],
    CAST('2023-07-19' AS DATE) AS [Column B],
    '"' AS [Frequency]
UNION
SELECT
    'Test2',
    CAST('2023-07-01' AS DATE),
    '"'
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT 'DTD' AS [Frequency]
    UNION
    SELECT 'WTD'
    UNION
    SELECT 'MTD'
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE1
FULL JOIN CTE2 ON 1=1
```

This outputs:

| Call | Column B | Frequency | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | " | DTD |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | " | MTD |
| Test1 | 2023-07-19 | " | WTD |
| Test2 | 2023-07-01 | " | DTD |
| Test2 | 2023-07-01 | " | MTD |
| Test2 | 2023-07-01 | " | WTD |

As you can see, the join always returns true, therefore duplicating every row of the first table with the number of rows in the second table.

Another approach to handle logic on the individual dates is to do a union for each Frequence.

T-SQL Example:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT 
        'Test1' AS [Call],
        CAST('2023-07-19' AS DATE) AS [Column B],
        '"' AS [Frequency]
    UNION
    SELECT
        'Test2',
        CAST('2023-07-01' AS DATE),
        '"'
)
SELECT 
    [Call] AS [Call],
    [Column B] AS [Column B],
    'DTD' AS [Frequency]
FROM CTE1
WHERE 1=1 --SOME LOGIC
UNION
SELECT 
    [Call] AS [Call],
    [Column B] AS [Column B],
    'MTD' AS [Frequency]
FROM CTE1
WHERE 1=1 --SOME LOGIC
UNION
SELECT 
    [Call] AS [Call],
    [Column B] AS [Column B],
    'YTD' AS [Frequency]
FROM CTE1
WHERE 1=1 --SOME LOGIC
```

This would return the same table but would give you the option to put in login for each Frequency type in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Where would i put the conditional logic to filter out dates? For example 7-01-2023 would not be DTD since today isnt the 19th, also it isnt this week ( july 17 to 23). The only row it should be in is MTD, YTD.